# 2x uplinks in HSRP - how to setup switch?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, lag, hsrp

Our ISP provides us with 2x 10G uplinks, and they use HSRP on their end. We see incoming traffic (load balanced) on both ports, but outgoing from us is only via one port. We only run L2 on our side (Cisco Nexus 5000). Now, what is the best practice for configuring these ports in our switch? Should we just have them as regular individual access ports or should we put them in a LAG? We have all ports in same VLAN.

The reason I ask is because we've noticed a speed decrease since we went from a single uplink to two, and I want to make sure it's configured properly on our side.

Comment: Do you have a router?

Comment: No, we're not doing any routing. We just simply run L2 with all ports in same VLAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ISP is providing two separate links and using HSRP to provide gateway redundancy over those two links, then you should not configure the links as a LAG.

HSRP only provides one active mac-address, which your network will learn on the link connected to the primary HSRP router.  The second link will have no outbound traffic (until HSRP fails over to the standby), but you will see inbound traffic from ISP on that link.

You could ask your ISP if they could create a LAG out of those two links on their side and you could match their config on your equipment. However they are running HSRP, which implies two separate systems for redundancy, so they will probably be unable to configure a LAG.

Comment: Exactly what I intended to right once my comment was answered :)